# Why the following error is coming in smarty foreach loop?

Tags: foreach, smarty

Following is my code of foreach loop in smarty template:

```
{if $question_detail.question_has_sub_ques=='yes' && $question_detail.sub_question}
      {foreach from=$question_detail.sub_question item=sub_ques_ans key=sub_ques_no}
      <tr class="oddRow">
        <td class="question">
          <h4><strong>Sub-question {$page_question_no+1}.{$sub_ques_no+1}</strong></h4>
          <ul class="options">
            <li><span>{$sub_ques_ans.question_text}</span></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td class="question-id">QUE{$sub_ques_ans.question_id}</td>
      </tr>
        {if $sub_ques_ans.question_file!=''}
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" colspan="2">
          <img src="{$ques_thum_image_path}{$sub_ques_ans.question_id}_{$sub_ques_ans.question_file}">
        </td>
      </tr>
        {/if}
        {if $question_detail.sub_question_answer_{$page_question_no+1}}
      <tr class="question_answer evenRow">
        <td class="question">
          <p class="answers"><strong>Answers</strong></p> 
          <ol class="options">
          **{foreach from=$question_detail.sub_question_answer_{$page_question_no+1} item=sub_ans key=sub_ans_no}**
            <li>
            {if $sub_ans.answer_is_right==1} {assign var='correct_sub_ans' value=$sub_ans_no+1} {/if}
            {if $sub_ans.answer_text!=''}{$sub_ans.answer_text}{/if}<br />
            {if $sub_ans.answer_file!=''}<img src="{$ans_thumb_img_path}{$sub_ans.answer_id}_{$sub_ans.answer_file}" >{/if}
            </li>  
          {/foreach}
          </ol>
          <p class="correct-answer"><strong>Correct Answer Option : </strong>{$correct_sub_ans}</p>
        </td>
        <td class="question-id">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
        {/if}  
      {/foreach}
    {/if}
```

I'm getting error as follows:

> Fatal error: Smarty error: [in question-details.tpl line 66]:
>
> syntax error: foreach: missing 'item' attribute (SmartyCompiler.php, line 1179) in /var/www/eprime/ocn/core/libs/Smarty.php on line 1095

And the line no.66 in my code is:

```
{foreach from=$question_detail.sub_question_answer_{$page_question_no+1} item=sub_ans key=sub_ans_no}
```

Can anyone help me in correcting this error? Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think smartydoes not accept `{} inside a {} ` like `{$page_question_no+1}` in your line n0 66

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{assign var="condition" value="{$question_detail.sub_question_answer}_{$page_question_no+1}"}
{foreach from=$condition item=sub_ans key=sub_ans_no}
 // do your code
{/foreach}
```